Why is the word output version of a DiagrammeR graph output distorted when compared with the html output and how do I fix this?
When rendering the below Rmd to a bookdown::html_document2 document everything looks fine. When I render it to an officedown::rdocx_document, however, I get a distorted and truncated version of the graph.
Why is that and how do I fix this?
---
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    base_format: "rmarkdown::word_document"
  bookdown::html_document2:
    toc: true
---

```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(officedown) # 0.3.0
library(DiagrammeR) # 1.0.9

create_graph() %>%
  add_balanced_tree(k = 2, h = 3) %>%
  render_graph()
```


Having both webshot and webshot2 installed can cause issues when rendering to docx.

When it becomes a Knitr or R Markdown sized plot, the default is 7in wide x 5in tall, which officedown converts to 5in wide by 4in wide, since the aspect ratio at 7:5 != 5:4 you get distortion.
2 options to fix:

You could manually set the graph to 5x4.
You can change the default knitr size to 5x4

Sizing the Graph Manually
To set the graph to a specific size, you have to define the pixels, not inches.
All that matters is that the width to height ratio is 5:4.
The larger the values you use the more crisp the image will be (and the bigger the file will be).
For example:
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: "2024-07-27"
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    base_format: "rmarkdown::word_document"
  bookdown::html_document2:
    toc: true
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(officedown)
library(DiagrammeR)

create_graph() %>% add_balanced_tree(k = 2, h = 3) %>% 
  render_graph(width = 1000, height = 800)
```

This is the word document on the left and the html on the right from this code.
 
Changing the Default Size
To change the default figure size in Knitr, you set this in output:
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: "2024-07-27"
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    base_format: "rmarkdown::word_document"
    fig_width: 5
    fig_height: 4
  bookdown::html_document2:
    toc: true
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(officedown)
library(DiagrammeR)

create_graph() %>% add_balanced_tree(k = 2, h = 3) %>% 
  render_graph(width = 1000, height = 800)
```

Here's the word and html again (left and right, respectively).
 

Thanks for the extensive answer. Unfortunately, however, even when running your code exactly I still see the unwanted distortions and the images do not look like in the screenshots here. Any ideas? What versions of officedown and DiagrammeR are you using?

Also, I'm working on Ubuntu 22.04 if that's relevant.

Sorry, i just noticed your comment. I'm using R 4.3.3., DiagrammeR 1.0.11 and officedown 0.3.3. As far as why this isn't working: are you opening this is MS Word? LibreOffice? Is your system set the imperial measurement system? Or is it set to the metric system? (I don't know why I assumed it would be Imperial; sorry about that either way.) Can look at the picture characteristics in the Word document? Right click on the picture, select "Size and Position". Is the image scaled?  Default reflects 50% x 36% for me. What's the original image size?

I've adjusted my officedown and DiagrammeR versions to match yours and the output is still garbled. My R is 4.3.2 but I can't change that quickly. I'm viewing the output with MS Word (German) based on a metric system. Image is scaled to 44% height and 103% width. Original size is 23.28cm height and 12.3cm width.

I know my responses are slow (I'm actually traveling in Germany right now...) I'm about to update my answer with what I think will work for you. It won't notify you of that update, but it will notify you of a new comment (hence the reason for the comment).

Thanks for the tenacity its appreciated. Unfortunately, the issue persists in my setup even after applying the suggested update.

I've now tried to reproduce my issue via a public Docker image rocker/r-ver:4.3.2 and it turns out that your solution works with a vanilla setup where I just install what is required to run this specific Rmd. At this point I assume that there something in my dependency tree that is creating problems.

I've narrowed it down to some interaction related to both webshot and webshot2 being installed in which case webshot2 (at least in my custom setup) seems to take priority. If I remove webshot2 from my setup then it works as expected with your original answer. My suggestestion is this to remove the update again and go back to the original answer, which I can then accept. I will also add a comment to my question indicating that having both webshot and webshot2 installed can cause issues.

Update removed… really glad you figured it out
